# Butt joints with screws

Tags: wood, screws, joints

I'm building a small wooden foundation for a new shed (pic below, joints in question highlighted). I'll be using wood screws to put it all together. My question is simple, should I be screwing through the perpendicular piece into the butt of the other piece ( =|| <##)? Or try to toenail the screw from the butt piece into the cross piece ( ##> =|| but a toenail angle)?

[image]

Comment: should i just butt screw it all and liquid nail all the connections?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that if you use a pre-drilled hole that includes a countersink using a tapered drill bit like this:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PQ9X9T4)*</sup>

...that it can be very easy to use 2 1/2" or 3" length deck type screws in either toe screw application or thru to end grain joining. If toe screwing is done properly with three screws it is ultimately stronger then screwing into the end grain of the wood at the butt joint. It does take some extra care to make sure that when tow screwing that you keep the member aligned with your layout marks. Often times I have found it useful to pre-drill all three pilot holes (two from one side and one on the other) and then start all the screws together. This way there will be less tendency for one of the angled screws to try to pull the piece off the line.

When using screw construction like this I prefer to use stainless steel screws with a square drive bit. Large screws with a Torx drive are also OK but can strip easier than a square drive in my opinion and experience. I also keep two power tools handy at the work site, one with the pilot drill and the other with the screw driver bit. I also prefer the screw driver tool to be a unit specifically designed for driving screws as they generally have lower RPM (more gear reduction) and thus more driving torque even at low speed selected on the variable speed trigger.

Comment: i don't have those drill bits, but i can counter sink my pilot holes. But you still haven't said which is best, butt screws or toe nail screws? I want to do just two butt screws into the cross piece end grain

Comment: I have brass looking screws, copper in color. I can check the actual numbers tomorrow

Comment: @CDspace The generic construction screws are not really good for use in exposed (i.e. outdoor) construction which is what it sounds like you have. You should also used pressure treated wood for this base.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I did get pressure treated wood. I have some screws that I think are outdoor rated. I'll have to check, but they have a grey power like coating?

Comment: @CDspace - For treated lumber you have to make sure to use screws that are rated compatible with treated lumber. I also gave my opinion on my evaluation of the toe screwing being stronger. Depending upon the width of your framing lumber two screws will not be enough to hold the butt joints together, For 2x6 I would say use four screws. 2x8 use five screws and 2x10 use six or seven screws. Also realize that screws into end grain are very weak and easy to spin out if only using 3" or 3.5" screws. If you want joints that will stay together in then I suggest using (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) four or six inch timber lock screws when doing butt joints into end grain. Pre-drill through the cross member with 1/4" drill and into the end grain a short way (total pre-drill about about 1" to 1.5" less than the timber lock screw length). I have built raised bed garden frames using 2x10 or 2x12 treated lumber with five screws per joint and they are staying very strong joints. https://www.amazon.com/FastenMaster-FMTLOK06-50-TimberLOK-Heavy-Duty-50-Count/dp/B000BD6AYG/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&th=1

Comment: @MichaelKaras Sorry, I didn't read it close enough. And thank you for the info on screws meant for treated wood, I did not know that.

Comment: I would second the recommendation for using a "structural" screw (TimberLock™ is one brand name), but not for "decking" screw. Decking screws are great for holding decking vertically down on top of joists, but I wouldn't count on them to hold a foundation together. I had to remove some screws holding down my deck's stair treads and found several 2 1/2" screws that had snapped on installation. I got part of the screw out, then, once the tread was pried off the rest of it, unscrewed the rest with locking pliers. NOT recommended for framing work!

Answer (score 0):

I would screw in from the perpendicular piece directly into the butt of the joist.  The only reason for toe-nailing or screw at an angle is because you don't have access to do the straight in screwing.

Comment: those short pieces indeed, I can't toe nail those